# search input field in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

[image]

Here I have `folderObjs` array and Console of this array is in below code, I put search input field and I want to make search for this array by folderName and  folderSize in angular how it is possible?

> HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs">
  <span>{{folder.folderName}}</span>
  <span>{{folder.folderSize}}</span>
</div>
```

> TS

```
folderObjs : Folder[] = [];

applyFilter(filterValue) {
  console.log(this.folderObjs);
// 0: {folderid: 781, folderName: "pelu folder",folderActivity: "true", …}
   1: {folderid: 782, folderName: "biju folder", folderActivity: "true", …}
   filter: "d"
   length: 2

  this.folderObjs.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: How you are going to take FolderSize input from user? Didn't see above.

Comment: @SameerAhmad see my edited question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create custom pipe

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';  
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, searchValue): any {
    if (!searchValue) return value;
    return value.filter((v) => 
    v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1 || 
    v.size.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1)

  }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
<input type="search"  [(ngModel)]="search">

<div *ngFor="let f of (folderObjs | filter:search)as folder">
  {{f.name}}
  {{f.size}}    
</div>

<div *ngIf="(folderObjs | filter:search).length <1">
  Not Found
  </div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrgzw3

Comment: The pipe 'filter' could not be found i got this type error in html

Comment: You need to include the filter pipe in app.module declaration array

Answer (score 1):

```
const folderObjs = [
    {name: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"},
    {name: "john", lastName: "Snow"},
    {name: "Tyrion", lastName: "Lannister"},
    {name: "Lorem", lastName: "Ipsum"},
]

applyFilter(filterValue) {
 folderObjs.filter((val) => {
    return val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1;
 });
}
```

above code will filter the data based name property.

```
applyFilter(filterValue, filterBy) {
 folderObjs.filter((val) => {
    return val[filterBy].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1;
 });
}
```

Can pass filterBy Option as well, Hope this helps

Comment: I got filtered array but how to hide other arrays

Comment: @Ankit if you want to do it in a clean way, create a filter pipe from my code, apply the pipe in front of <div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs | filterPipe: filterValue"> the pipe will return the filtered element and the dom will update the list accordingly, if you need help creating a filter pipe, i will help you

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can use either pipes or filter() to achieve this.

```
sortedArray : Folder[] = [];  

applyFilter(val: string) {

  this.sortedArray = this.folderObjs.filter(x =>
    x.folderName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
    x.folderSize.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
}
```

Comment: I get searched value but how to hide other folder

Comment: Use the sortedArray in your *ngFor so you can hide other folders

Answer (score 1):

This will work, **first take a copy of the folderObjs to folderObjCopy** since when search value is empty we must repopulate all the values.

```
applyFilter(filterValue) {
 let val = filterValue.toLowerCase();
 let searchColumns = ['folderName','folderSize'];
 if (val.length > 0) {
 this.folderObjs = this.folderObjCopy.filter(function (d) {
          let matchFound = false;
          for (let data of search_columns) {
            let value = "" + d[data];
            if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) {
              matchFound = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          return matchFound;
        });
 } else {
        this.folderObjs = this.folderObjCopy;
   }
 }
```

**Note** : There will be much more optimised solutions, this is just my implementations. Please let me know if this doesn't work